# The class is not found from the closure

Tags: php, class

This is my `ErrorHandler` class, I register the handlers from the main `Application` class calling `ErrorHandler::init();`

I don't understand why but the class `ErrorResponse` is not found in `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler`.

However the class is found in `register_shutdown_function`... that's pretty weird.

Could you know which can be the reason which the `ErrorResponse` class is not found in the other handlers?

```
<?php

namespace tools\exception;

use tools\core\http\ErrorResponse;

class ErrorHandler
{
    static public function init()
    {
        self::_registerNormalErrorHandler();
        self::_registerExceptionErrorHandler();
        self::_registerFatalErrorHandler();
    }

    static private function _registerNormalErrorHandler()
    {
        set_error_handler(function ($err_code, $err_message, $err_file, $err_line)
        {
                $responseCode = 500;
                ErrorResponse::create(
                    $responseCode,
                    $err_file,
                    $err_message,
                    $err_line,
                    "set_error_handler")->sendJSON();

                die();
        });
    }
    static private function _registerExceptionErrorHandler()
    {
        set_exception_handler(function ($exception)
        {
                $responseCode = $exception->getCode();
                if(0 === $responseCode)
                    $responseCode = 500;

                ErrorResponse::create(
                    $responseCode,
                    $exception->getFile(),
                    $exception->getMessage(),
                    $exception->getLine(),
                    "set_exception_handler")->sendJSON();

                die();
        });
    }
    static private function _registerFatalErrorHandler()
    {
        register_shutdown_function(function ()
        {
            $last_error = error_get_last();
            if( null !== $last_error ) {

                $isError = false;
                switch ($last_error["type"]) {
                    // ...
                }
                if($isError) {
                    ErrorResponse::create(
                        500,
                        $last_error['file'],
                        $last_error['message'],
                        $last_error['line'],
                        $caught)->sendJSON();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full qualified class name?

Comment: I tried to use require_once() from the front controller and it worked, but it is not cleaned, I'd like to use the autoload.

Comment: if you mean to put tools\core\http\ErrorResponse::create(/* ... */)->sendJSON() I also tried it and it didn't work :(

Comment: check the namespace that youve given ErrorResponse:: itself

Comment: I think all of that is correct because ErrorResponse class is found on **register_shutdown_function** handler...how can it be possible? it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :D, the problem was the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) it was making the class not found error...I found the Declaration of compatible... (the normal error you get when you don't respect [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)) in some log.

The ErrorResponse is the child of Response class and both had a **factory method** called `create()` to instantiate them. I removed the factory method on `ErrorResponse` and I instantiate it using the normal way `new ErrorResponse( ... )`